# What are the ways to convert a String into runnable code?

Tags: scala

I could not find how to convert a String into runnable code, for instance:

```
val i = "new String('Yo')"
// conversion
println(i)
```

should print

```
Yo
```

after the conversion.

I found the following example in another post:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop
import java.io.StringReader
import java.io.StringWriter
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.io.BufferedReader
import scala.tools.nsc.Settings

object FuncRunner extends App {

  val line = "sin(2 * Pi * 400 * t)"

  val lines = """import scala.math._
    |var t = 1""".stripMargin

  val in = new StringReader(lines + "\n" + line + "\nval f = (t: Int) => " + line)
  val out = new StringWriter

  val settings = new Settings

  val looper = new ILoop(new BufferedReader(in), new PrintWriter(out))
  val res = looper process settings
  Console println s"[$res] $out"
}
```

link: [How to convert a string from a text input into a function in a Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965400/how-to-convert-a-string-from-a-text-input-into-a-function-in-a-scala)

But it seems like scala.tools is not available anymore, and I'm a newbie in Scala so i could not figure out how to replace it.
And may be there are just other ways to do it now.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simple execute your code contained inside String using Quasiquotes(Experimental Module).

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

// TO compile and run code we will use a ToolBox api.
val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()

// write your code starting with q  and put it inside double quotes.
// NOTE : you will have to use triple quotes if you have any double quotes usage in your code.
val code1 = q"""new String("hello")"""
//compile and run your code.
val result1 = toolbox.compile(code1)()

// another example
 val code2 = q"""
 case class A(name:String,age:Int){
    def f = (name,age)
 }
 val a = new A("Your Name",22)
 a.f
 """

 val result2 = toolbox.compile(code2)()
```

Output in REPL :

```
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
toolbox: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@69b34f89
code1: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = new String("hello")
result1: Any = hello
code2: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree =
{
  case class A extends scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val name: String = _;
    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val age: Int = _;
    def <init>(name: String, age: Int) = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def f = scala.Tuple2(name, age)
  };
  val a = new A("Your Name", 22);
  a.f
}
result2: Any = (Your Name,22)

scala>
```

To learn more about Quasiquotes :
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/setup.html

Comment: This syntax is pretty cool thank you, do you have an idea on how to use an existing class between those triple quote?

Comment: You have to read about it more here : http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution using the ToolBox tool :

```
val cm = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val tb = cm.mkToolBox()

val str = tb.eval(tb.parse("new String(\"Yo\")"))

println(str)
```

This is printing:

```
Yo
```

Comment: I am not able to find this scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox library...can you please help me with this....

Answer (score 1):

The scala compiler (and the "interpreter loop") are available [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.11.7). For example:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/ILoop.scala

A compiled jar that has that class will be in your scala distribution under `lib\scala-compiler.jar`.

Comment: But on there website http://scala-tools.org/, they are saying "We are no longer providing any support for scala-tools.org.", are they only talking about the website? If they're also talking about the library, it might be unwise to use it right?

Comment: @Charrette: The scala compiler is actually maintained by Typesafe. So it's safe to use it.

Answer (score -2):

One way could be to take/parse that `string` code and then write it yourself in some file as Scala code. This way it would be executed by Scala compiler when you will call it.

An example: just like Scala is doing with Java. It takes this code and then convert it into Java by making use of `main` method.

```
object Xyz extends App {
 println ("Hello World!")
}
```